# How can I access public folder files after build of vue electron project?

Tags: vue.js, electron

I'm making project with vue and electron.In development mode, my program works well.
But, After build, it looks like I can't access public folder since it is converted to something&somewhere else. Anyone can tell me how to access my model.json file in built program?
[structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nos8X.png)
[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OnoDp.png)
expecting rectified code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.